Type 'DOMTokenList' is not an array type - Error while converting DOMTokenList with spread operator
Type 'DOMTokenList' is not an array type - Error while converting DOMTokenList with spread operator. I use Typescript/Playwright for automation. I am trying to get the classlist of a div element. I used Array.from and I got an eslint error to prefer spread operator.
I wrote:
let classes = (await this.emailOptionsPage.getMobileView().first().evaluate(classdiv => [...classdiv.classList] as string[]))[0];

The classList shows an error saying DOMTokenList is not an arraytype.
How do I proceed?
If there is a better way to get the classList, that would be great too.

Array.from(classdiv.classList) ?

You need to add DOM.Iterable to your libs entry in your tsconfig.json.
